# how to duplicate the characters in between the first and last characters, of a given word?

Tags: java, string, character

hey so I'm working on a question that gives me a word and then asks for me to duplicate the letters in between the first and last letters of that word by some number.

I tried to learn how to duplicate the characters through other posts, but I think I'm doing it totally wrong. Can someone help?

this is what I have

```
public String stretch(String s, int n){
    char first = s.charAt(0);
    char last = s.charAt(s.length()-1);
    String result = "";
   for(int i = 1; i < s.length()-2; i++)
         for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
             result += first +s.charAt(i)+ last;

   return first +result+ last;
```

Comment: I do not understand, if i put `("example", 2)` the output should be `exxaammpplle`?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Comment: I can't get your JUnit. What is trying to test? also i need SEED data, and what is sp?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class mainProgram
{

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        String word = "example";
        String result = stretch ( word , 2 );
        System.out.println ( result );
    }

    public static String stretch(String s, int n){
        char first = s.charAt(0);
        char last = s.charAt(s.length()-1);
        String result = "";
       for(int i = 1; i < s.length()-1; i++)
       {
           for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
           result += s.charAt(i);
       }

       return first +result+ last;
    }

}
```

Comment: this doesn't work when I use it against the Junit tester that my prof has provided me. I'm not sure what is wrong. I did something similar to this, check my update to the post. But yeah still not working. Thanks for your help tho!

Comment: @JVAN try to run my edit. May you attach your JUnit tests?

Comment: I added the tester. its not passing it :/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line:

```
return s.replaceAll("(?<!^).(?!$)", new String(new char[n]).replace("\0", "$0"));
```

Breaking it down:

- the find regex matches every char except the first and last (negative look behind and negative look ahead assert this)
- the replacement term is `n` copies of `$0`, which is the match

Comment: @jvan I guarantee your teacher/professor couldn't do it as 1337 as this either :)